# Does "removeEventListener" (android) close Firebase Realtime Database connection?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I went through all the docs and so many blogs but did not get an answer.

Thing is that I have an initial free quota of 100 simultaneous connections to the firebase realtime database.That means at a time 100 of my users can use my application.After using the application unless and until a user does not `destroy` the application the `connection` still remains open for that user so at the meantime no other user can get access.

So my question is that if I remove the listener from the Database Reference will this close the `connection` as well?

```
 ValueEventListener listener = null;
 DatabaseRefference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRefference("user");
 listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ref.removeEventListener(listener); 
        //----Doing Stuffs
    }
 }
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```

With this what I want to achieve is that when User1 gets his search result he/she will no longer hold a `connection` and in this way another user can get into the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase automatically manages the connection.  This is explained in the [Realtime Database Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state):

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce
>   bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no
>   pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly
>   disconnected by the goOffline method, Firebase closes the connection
>   after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Also note that when a listener is added with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` it is automatically removed after `onDataChange()` runs.  You don't need to call `removeEventListenter()`, as you have done in the posted code.  This is described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once):

> **Read data once**
>
> In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then
>   immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you
>   don't expect to change. You can use the
>   addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to simplify this scenario: it
>   triggers once and then does not trigger again.

You can [detect connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) changes with a listener at pseudo-location `/.info/connected`.  Note that this does count as a normal, "active" listener and will not inhibit the auto-disconnect processing.

Another way to get visiblilty on the connection state management is to enable debug logging with [FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)).

Comment: Thanks, man. I was confused about this. Working with realtime database along with android jetpack component and mvvm architecture is a real hassle.